# Gulp package-solution not using the Angular.json file when deployed in SPFX

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

I have an SPFX solution where I deploy a bundle.JS file generated by an external Angular project as detailed here:
https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/howtos/angularelements/

I have noticed that my solution behaves differently when I test it on the local workbench (using gulp serve) and when I test it in the deployed website (using gulp package-solution --ship after en gulp bundle--ship) 
I have some Angular files missing like the Angular.JSON is not used (I miss the jquery import for instance) and some other packages coming from the Angular solution are not imported.

Is it possible to configure the gulp package-solution command to get the same configuration as the gulp serve ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gulp bundle --ship
gulp bundle --debug
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Comment: Whats is the purpose of the gulp bundle --debug ? 

I have already configured a guld sequence running gulp clean, gulp bundle --ship and gulp package-solution --ship but still I cannot find a way to deploy fully my Angular.JSON package for instance